# How to find MASTER_IP and MASTER_CLUSTER_IP in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes

I am following [this guide and trying to create the TLS cert](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/certificates/), I am using `cfssl` and I am able to create the required file, but what should I provide for `MASTER_IP` and `MASTER_CLUSTER_IP`?

When I execute `kubectl cluster-info`, I can only see the following information:

```
Kubernetes control plane is running at https://xxx.yy.zzz.40:6443
CoreDNS is running at https://xxx.yy.zzz.40:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Where can I find these two values?

Answer (score 1):

Use below command

```
kubectl get no -owide
```

The above command displays internal and external ips of all the nodes in the cluster

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).